# Correct Compiler choosing in Qt when using MSVC kits

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

I know that Qt automatically detects MSVC compilers but sometimes it didn't work as expected!
As I posted in the image I want to know what is meaning of each compiler naming and for which kit I should choose one of these compilers?
for example what are the differences between amd64 and x86-amd64 and should I choose amd64 for compiling on 64 bit machine to the 64 bit machine target?

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QySg.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIOzI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first name refers to what is the type of the compiler executable, or in other words refers to the type of the OS architecture that is needed to run the compiler.
while the other name refers to the type of the executable that is produced by the compiler

for example `x86-amd64` means that the compiler can run on a 32 bit system & produces 64 bit executables, while `amd64` only means that the compiler runs on 64 bit system & produces 64 bit executables

i hope i could explain it as clear as possible