# Qt can't detect MSVC compiler

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to run Qt app with MSVC and Cmake. But MSVC compiler is not detected. How to fix the error?

I downloaded Qt 6.5.3 from official installer, downloaded MSVC2019 kit, downloaded CMake (cmake version 3.29.0-rc1) on my Windows10 PC virtual box

Then I am creating a new Qt project (was trying several project types), selecting MSVC Kit and see error

> No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found

I read [Correct Compiler choosing in Qt when using MSVC kits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58048568/correct-compiler-choosing-in-qt-when-using-msvc-kits) but In my case I even don't see compilers in Kits -> Compilers (see picture)

Also I downloaded Windows Dev Kit from tis page https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/

My Kit details:
[image]

I was trying to restart PC / reinstall QT but it didn't help, I was googling and found recomendation to "re-detect compilers" but it didn't help, I still see no compilers:
[image]

UPDATE - downloaded visual studio, but it didn't help: [image]

Comment: Install this https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/.

Comment: What components should I install?

Comment: Desktop Development with C++, obviously.

Comment: I downloaded Visual Studion 2022 and  Desktop Development with C++, restarted PC, but it didn't help

Comment: @273K attached Visual Studio downloads screen

Comment: You may need to start Qt Creator from the `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022`. There are path and environment things that need to be set when not using Visual Studio.

Comment: It should find MSVC. Have you tried the "Re-detect" button or look at "Auto-detection Settigns"?

Comment: @jkb I tried C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community>C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\qtcreator.exe but it didn't help